# How to pass command line arguments to Cake (Frosting), when these arguments are already collected with System.CommandLine?

Tags: c#, .net, cakebuild, system.commandline

I'm developing a .net tool for building our projects. I'm using System.CommandLine package for collect command line argument without sweat. My build command looks like this:

```cs
    [Command(Description = "Runs build process")]
    public class Build
    {
        public int Execute(
            [Option] string targetDirectory,
            [Option(Aliases = new[] {"-c"})] string configuration = "Release")
        {
            return new CakeHost()
                .UseContext<BuildContext>()
                .Run(Enumerable.Empty<string>());
        }
    }
```

Note that there are attributes not available in the Microsoft's library. It's my addition. Type is converted into `Command` on the fly.

The important thing is that `Cake` takes arguments only as string collection. So the only way I can see here, is to convert arguments into strings and parse it again inside a task. I will not able to sleep for a month if I do that.

The solution I would expect here is to create and pass an instance of `BuildContext` type (it inherits from `FrostingContext`). I could simply have properties corresponding to app arguments.

Any ideas how to workaround it? Or maybe there is a feature I don't know?

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you could use dependency injection to inject your custom arguments into your own build context as a singleton.

This could look something like

```
[Command(Description = "Runs build process")]
public class Build
{
    public int Execute(
        [Option] string targetDirectory,
        [Option(Aliases = new[] {"-c"})] string configuration = "Release")
        => new CakeHost()
                    .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton(new BuildParameters(targetDirectory, configuration)))
                    .UseContext<BuildContext>()
                    .Run(Array.Empty<string>());
}
```

In this case, `BuildParameters` is defined like this

```
public class BuildParameters
{
    public DirectoryPath TargetDirectory { get; }
    public string Configuration { get; }

    public BuildParameters(string targetDirectory, string configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        TargetDirectory = DirectoryPath.FromString(targetDirectory);
    }
}
```

A minimal FrostingContext utilizing this

```
public class BuildContext : FrostingContext
{
    public BuildParameters BuildParameters { get; }

    public BuildContext(ICakeContext context, BuildParameters buildParameters)
        : base(context)
    {
        BuildParameters = buildParameters;
    }
}
```

And then in all your Frosting tasks, you'll have a `BuildParameters` property you can access like this.

```
[TaskName("Hello")]
public sealed class HelloTask : FrostingTask<BuildContext>
{
    public override void Run(BuildContext context)
    {
        context.Log.Information("Configuration {0}", context.BuildParameters.Configuration);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel you have two ways to go about this:

If you want to use Cake Frosting, which is meant to parse command line arguments, you'd have to pass all the arguments you are given, something like

```cs
new CakeHost()
 .UseContext<BuildContext>()
 .Run(new[]
  {
    $"--configuration={configuration}"
  });
```

(Alternatively, you could check if `System.CommandLine` contains a feature to access the arguments "raw" as they were given.)

Or, if you want to do all the parsing and setup in "your" app, you should have a look at [Cake.Bridge](https://github.com/devlead/Cake.Bridge) which allows for using Cake-features fully programmatically. (IMHO this is the longer/harder path)